# Numba - How to fill 2D array in parallel

Tags: python, vectorization, numba

I have a function that operates on a 2D matrix on float64(x,y). Basic concept: for each combination of rows (no. rows choose 2) count the number of positiv values after subtraction (row1 - row2). In a 2Dmatrix of int64(y,y) store this value in index [row1,row2] if value is above a certain threshold and [row2,row1] if below.

I've implemented that and decorated it with @njit(parallel=False), that works fine @njit(parallel=True) seems to give no speedup. Trying to speed up the whole thing I had a look at @guvectorize, that works as well. However I'm not able to figure out how to use @guvectorize with parallel true in this case either.

I had a look at [numba guvectorize target='parallel' slower than target='cpu'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35350689/numba-guvectorize-target-parallel-slower-than-target-cpu) , where the solution was to use @vecorize instead, but I can not transfer the solution to my problem, therefore I am now seeking help :)

Basic jitted and guvectorized implementation

```py
import numpy as np
from numba import jit, guvectorize, prange
import timeit

@jit(parallel=False)
def check_pairs_sg(raw_data):
    # 2D array to be filled
    result = np.full((len(raw_data), len(raw_data)), -1)

    # Iterate over all possible gene combinations
    for r1 in range(0, len(raw_data)):
        for r2 in range(r1+1, len(raw_data)):
            diff = np.subtract(raw_data[:, r1], raw_data[:, r2])

            num_pos = len(np.where(diff > 0)[0])

            # Arbitrary check to illustrate
            if num_pos >= 5: 
               result[r1,r2] = num_pos
            else:
               result[r2,r1] = num_pos

    return result

@jit(parallel=True)
def check_pairs_multi(raw_data):
    # 2D array to be filled
    result = np.full((len(raw_data), len(raw_data)), -1)

    # Iterate over all possible gene combinations
    for r1 in range(0, len(raw_data)):
        for r2 in prange(r1+1, len(raw_data)):
            diff = np.subtract(raw_data[:, r1], raw_data[:, r2])

            num_pos = len(np.where(diff > 0)[0])

            # Arbitrary check to illustrate
            if num_pos >= 5: 
               result[r1,r2] = num_pos
            else:
               result[r2,r1] = num_pos

    return result

@guvectorize(["void(float64[:,:], int64[:,:])"],
             "(n,m)->(m,m)", target='cpu')
def check_pairs_guvec_sg(raw_data, result):
    for r1 in range(0, len(result)):
        for r2 in range(r1+1, len(result)):
            diff = np.subtract(raw_data[:, r1], raw_data[:, r2])

            num_pos = len(np.where(diff > 0)[0])

            # Arbitrary check to illustrate
            if num_pos >= 5: 
               result[r1,r2] = num_pos
            else:
               result[r2,r1] = num_pos

@guvectorize(["void(float64[:,:], int64[:,:])"],
             "(n,m)->(m,m)", target='parallel')
def check_pairs_guvec_multi(raw_data, result):
    for r1 in range(0, len(result)):
        for r2 in range(r1+1, len(result)):
            diff = np.subtract(raw_data[:, r1], raw_data[:, r2])

            num_pos = len(np.where(diff > 0)[0])

            # Arbitrary check to illustrate
            if num_pos >= 5: 
               result[r1,r2] = num_pos
            else:
               result[r2,r1] = num_pos

if __name__=="__main__":
     np.random.seed(404)
     a = np.random.random((512,512)).astype(np.float64)
     res = np.full((len(a), len(a)), -1)
```

and measured with

```py
%timeit check_pairs_sg(a)
%timeit check_pairs_multi(a)
%timeit check_pairs_guvec_sg(a, res)
%timeit check_pairs_guvec_multi(a, res)
```

resulting in:

```
614 ms ± 2.54 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
507 ms ± 6.87 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
622 ms ± 3.88 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
671 ms ± 4.35 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

I cat wrap my head around on how to implement this as @vectorized or a proper parallel @guvectorize to fill the resulting 2D array truely in parallel.

I guess this is my first step before trying to taking this further to gpu.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: "I guess this is my first step before trying to taking this further to gpu.". Are you sure that you can't get rid of the nested `for` loops first before even turning to `numba`?

Comment: It's not clear to me how I should run this to have a go at doing that because you have two `if __name__ == '__main__'` guards

Comment: Well I could use ```itertools``` to yield a combination tuple after the other, to only have one loop, but how would that help?
ps: i removed the second main

Comment: Well, it looks like you could also use `np.roll()` to offset by 1 instead of the inner loop but I can't tell because I don't know what the function is doing.

Comment: In fact, I'm pretty sure most of this could be vectorized, dropping some `for` loops and the `if` checks too. Jumping to numba and then to GPU before ensuring the numpy approach is appropriate is neglecting the problem.

Comment: Sorry if the example is limited and too vague. If you like you can have a look at the full code and its purpose at https://github.com/rfechtner/pypairs/blob/master/pypairs/tools/sandbag.py

Comment: Please give an example of `raw_data` and I can have a go at vectorizing it (realistically I'm aware that this will just be randomly generated data but I'm curious what it should look like)

Comment: first of: thank you very much for your time. I really appreciate it!

you could use ```np.random.uniform(low=0.5, high=13.3, size=(10,10))```. Or you can have a look at [test_sandbag](https://github.com/rfechtner/pypairs/blob/master/pypairs/tests/test_sandbag.py)

Comment: Are you sure this code works? I get the same result every single time, regardless of the random input. I'm looking specifically at `check_pairs_sg`

Comment: ```np.random.seed(404);
test = np.random.random((10,10)).astype(np.float64);
res_a = check_pairs_sg(test);
np.random.seed(343);
test = np.random.random((10,10)).astype(np.float64);
res_b = check_pairs_sg(test);
np.allclose(res_a,res_b)
``` 
=> False

Comment: I haven't set a seed. _Without_ a seed it still gives the same answer, so the result is deterministic regardless of any random input.

Comment: That goes completely against the premise in your first paragraph. Why should my output _always_ be the same if the input numbers are random and changing? In that case, you might as well just return a fixed array and completely ignore the input to the function or anything in the function body

Comment: ```np.random.seed(404);
test_a = np.random.random((10,10)).astype(np.float64);
res_a = check_pairs_sg(test_a);
test_b = np.random.random((10,10)).astype(np.float64);
res_b = check_pairs_sg(test_b);
print(np.allclose(test_a,test_b)) // False;
print(np.allclose(res_a,res_b)) // False;
```

Sorry I cant quite follow you, the algorithm is deterministic: same input -> same output; other random input -> other random output

Comment: Ok, sorry, I'm missing something here because I can see what you're trying to illustrate but the output on my screen simply does not match it. I'm visually inspecting the outputs for a smaller sample and it's just always the same. Perhaps it's not possible for me to scale the approach back to something I can visually test against

Comment: https://repl.it/@RonFechtner/ElderlyInvolvedDesigns

Comment: Your access pattern to the array is suboptimal. This has a high impact on performance (numpy-arrays are by default C-Ordered). One other problem is to create temporary arrays..

Comment: @max9111 could you elaborate more? I understand that in c ordered arrays the last index is the frequent one. How would a fortan ordered help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Think of other compiled languages when writing Numba code

For example think of a more or less exact equivalent implementation of the lines

```
diff = np.subtract(raw_data[:, r1], raw_data[:, r2])
num_pos = len(np.where(diff > 0)[0])
```

in C++.

**Pseudo Code**

- Allocate an Array diff, loop over raw_data[i*size_dim_1+r1] (loop index is i)
- Allocate a Boolean Array, loop over the whole array diff and check if diff[i]>0
- Loop over the Boolean Array, get the indices where b_arr==True and save them via vector::push_back() to a vector.
- Check the size of the vector

**The main problems in your code are:**

- Creating temporary arrays for simple operations
- Non-contigous memory access

### Optimizing the code

**Removing temporary arrays and simplification**

```
@nb.njit(parallel=False)
def check_pairs_simp(raw_data):
    # 2D array to be filled
    result = np.full((raw_data.shape[0],raw_data.shape[1]), -1)
    
    # Iterate over all possible gene combinations
    for r1 in range(0, raw_data.shape[1]):
        for r2 in range(r1+1, raw_data.shape[1]):
            num_pos=0
            for i in range(raw_data.shape[0]):
                if (raw_data[i,r1]>raw_data[i,r2]):
                    num_pos+=1
            
            # Arbitrary check to illustrate
            if num_pos >= 5: 
               result[r1,r2] = num_pos
            else:
               result[r2,r1] = num_pos
    
    return result
```

**Removing temporary arrays and simplification + contigous memory access**

```
@nb.njit(parallel=False)
def check_pairs_simp_rev(raw_data_in):
    #Create a transposed array not just a view 
    raw_data=np.ascontiguousarray(raw_data_in.T)
    
    # 2D array to be filled
    result = np.full((raw_data.shape[0],raw_data.shape[1]), -1)
    
    # Iterate over all possible gene combinations
    for r1 in range(0, raw_data.shape[0]):
        for r2 in range(r1+1, raw_data.shape[0]):
            num_pos=0
            for i in range(raw_data.shape[1]):
                if (raw_data[r1,i]>raw_data[r2,i]):
                    num_pos+=1
            
            # Arbitrary check to illustrate
            if num_pos >= 5: 
               result[r1,r2] = num_pos
            else:
               result[r2,r1] = num_pos
    
    return result
```

**Removing temporary arrays and simplification + contigous memory access + Parallelization**

```
@nb.njit(parallel=True,fastmath=True)
def check_pairs_simp_rev_p(raw_data_in):
    #Create a transposed array not just a view 
    raw_data=np.ascontiguousarray(raw_data_in.T)
    
    # 2D array to be filled
    result = np.full((raw_data.shape[0],raw_data.shape[1]), -1)
    
    # Iterate over all possible gene combinations
    for r1 in nb.prange(0, raw_data.shape[0]):
        for r2 in range(r1+1, raw_data.shape[0]):
            num_pos=0
            for i in range(raw_data.shape[1]):
                if (raw_data[r1,i]>raw_data[r2,i]):
                    num_pos+=1
            
            # Arbitrary check to illustrate
            if num_pos >= 5: 
               result[r1,r2] = num_pos
            else:
               result[r2,r1] = num_pos
    
    return result
```

**Timings**

```
%timeit check_pairs_sg(a)
488 ms ± 8.68 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit check_pairs_simp(a)
186 ms ± 3.83 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
%timeit check_pairs_simp_rev(a)
12.1 ms ± 226 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
%timeit check_pairs_simp_rev_p(a)
5.43 ms ± 49.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: Instead of using `if (raw_data[r1,i]-raw_data[r2,i]) > 0` you could also use `if raw_data[r1,i] > raw_data[r2,i]`

Comment: @ MSeifert Thanks for the comment. This gives another 10% speedup

Comment: Hey max9111 thank you very much for the insights. Your answer not only helped to improve my code significantly but also made me understand a lot about numpy. Cheers